# Regional blocking on cloud run external api calls

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, google-cloud-run

I have a scraper in cloud run job that makes different calls to external APIs.

The external server started to block by region, it only accepts IPs from Chile and my scraper stopped working.
I directly tested the requests on a VM created in the Santiago/Chile region on GCP and it worked, in any other region it failed.

So I tried to use the Santiago/Chile region in the Cloud Run Job, but I still have the same problem.

I don't know if the output requests go through another GCP region.
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution

In order to get the requests to be from the Santiago/Chile region, I created a VPC with a Cloud Nat with a Cloud Router in Santiago/Chile region.

Then I created the Cloud Run Job in the Santiago/Chile region as well and finally I connected it to the newly created VPC, with a Serverless VPC Access.

The solution was pretty obvious after I figured it out.